# Dropdown Menu Dummy Link

Tags: 7, routes, navigation

One of my menu items I have, I want to make it so that only the child links are clickable, and the parent is not. Is there a way to make the parent a sort of "Dummy Link" just to set a hierarchy for a menu?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Special Menu Items](http://drupal.org/project/special_menu_items) module will do exactly that for you:

> Special menu items is a Drupal module that provides placeholder and separator menu items.
>
> A placeholder is a menu item which is not a link. It is useful with dynamic drop down menus where we want to have a parent menu item which is not linking to a page but just acting as a parent grouping some menu items below it.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. I'll set as answer as soon as the 10 minutes are up.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use another module:

In your custom module you could implement [hook_menu_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) (Or if you created the menu using [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7), you could use this same approach there).  You could probably make the parent item a [MENU_CALLBACK](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/constant/MENU_CALLBACK/7) that does nothing e.g. it could `return TRUE` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

http://drupal.org/project/menu_firstchild Also provides similar functionality with the exception that the main link s given the link of the first child so that you preserve usability.